# Windows Forms Data Binding - Manipulate Data Before Giving It To Control

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to write a piece of software that will take values from an MSSQL database and put it into a DataGridView, for which the data binding feature of  Visual Studio is perfect. The problem is that I want to format/manipulate the information from the database before it gets to the control.

For example, in one database table I have an entry called UserTypeID that contains integers, and another table maps the UserTypeID into a String UserType like "Admin", "Operator", "Guest", etc. I want to be able to take the UserTypeID from the first table, translate it into its String equivalent through the second table, then pass the result on to the DataGridView.

Is there a reasonably simple way to do this, or is something that would require an intermediary object or whatever?

Comment: Are you asking how to perform the specific manipulation, or just how to perform manipulations in general, prior to databinding?

Comment: @Tyrsius In general. This specific manipulation is an example of what I want it to do.

Comment: This is actually quite simple. Before setting the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` to whatever object is holding your data, perform whatever manipulations you need to.

Comment: @Tyrsius Are you talking about assigning the DataSource programmatically? If so, would I need a second DataSource to hold the new/manipulated values to give to the DataGridView?

Comment: I am talking about assigning the datasource programmatically. You will not need a second datasource to do this. Unless you make these manipulations inside the `dataAdapter`, you will need to do this programmatically.

Comment: If the displayed data will be read-only (not written back to the DB), and you have a second table with the human-readable user types per `UserTypeID`, then why don't you `JOIN` the two tables and then `SELECT` the description from the second table, instead of the ID from the first table...? That way there won't be any need to preprocess the `DataTable` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the strings are static (will not add / delete by the user ) then the easiest way is to create a List<> or an array for the strings and a small extension method like this

```
string[] m = new string[] { "Guest", "Admin", "Operator", "Unit Manager", "User" }

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m">the string array which searches for the integer criteria.</param>
/// <param name="s"> the int32 number which will pass to the index of the array </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string IntToString( this string S, string[] m, int s)
{
    string z = m.ElementAt(s);
    //Array.Clear(m, 0, m.Length);

    /// if you will need to clear the string array elements each using of this method then delete the comment slashes in front of the Array.Clear() method

   /// in Array.Clear method also -to depends of your need- you can disable to show the
   /// Array elements.. May be you will need only 1 admin and if an admin chooosen you can delete this option by changing the parameters of Array.Clear() Method

    return z;
}
```

and a simple usage example in a Data Access Layer class :

```
string g;

if (dataReader["yourIntValueFromTable"] != DBNull.Value)
{                           
   yourClassObject.yourIntValueFromTable = (int)dataReader["yourIntValueFromTable"]; 

   yourClassObject.yourStringValue = g.IntToString(m, ((int)dataReader["yourIntValueFromTable"]));

}
```

after fill this class you can set as datasource to wherever you want.

but, if your strings are dynamic then you need to create a Stored Proc and call your values from there

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @Tyrsius suggested. But,if you are using a collection of objects as your datasource, you can do the manipulations in the GET method for that property. Thats what I would  do!

Answer (score -1):

From your SQL perform the necessary join and include the necessary columns in the returned result

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userName, u.userTypeID, ut.userTypeName
FROM Users u
JOIN UserType ut ON u.userTypeID = ut.userTypeID
```

That gives you the extra columns you need in the datagridview.
If you are using DataTable this would be easy as it can contain variable number of columns. Just bing the datatable to your datagridview

For collection of objects, you will have extra properties:

```
class User
{
    int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    string UserTypeName { get; set; } // this could also be readonly depending on how you want it set
}
```